# SSD configuration software

Tags: ssd, macos

Both Intel and Samsung supply windows only configuration software for their SSDs ([Intel® Solid State Drive Toolbox](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18455/Intel-Solid-State-Drive-Toolbox), [Samsung Magician Software for PC](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html)).

Is there anyway to achieve the same functionality under OS X?
And/Or is this functionality actually needed?

To clarify using Intel as an example (but samsung has something similar), their configuration tool can:

> Check and **tune** system settings for optimal performance, power
>   efficiency, and endurance

(Note that this is separate from firmware updates - which both companies do seem to support for OS X systems)

Answer (score 1):

Both of those tools seem to provide some basic diagnostic information about your drive.

> The Intel® Solid State Drive Toolbox (Intel® SSD Toolbox) is drive
>   management software that allows you to:
>   - View current drive information for Intel® Solid State Drives (Intel® SSDs), including:
>
> - Model number, capacity, and firmware version
> - Drive health
> - Estimated drive life remaining
> - SMART attributes (also available for hard disk
>     drives and non-Intel SSDs)
> - Identify Device information (also available for hard disk drives and non-Intel SSDs)

You can get this with [DiskDrill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) or [Diskwarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/).  The free versions of both can give you what you are looking for.

The "tuning" is basically enabling/disabling TRIM support.  There are 3rd party utilities out there that can do it for you, but the **reccomended** way is doing it through [OS X Terminal](http://www.mactrast.com/2013/11/enable-trim-ssds-os-x-mavericks/).  The linked article has a Word document that provides you the steps to to enable TRIM; I am direct linking it [here](http://www.mactrast.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/TRIM-SUPPORT-SSD.doc)

Comment: You again!  Anyway it's the `**tune** system settings for optimal performance, power efficiency, and endurance` aspect that I am more interested in.

Comment: It's more than just enabling TRIM.  The Samsung software allows you to select between 3 or 4 different "modes": Maximum Performance, Maximum Capacity and Maximum Reliability .. http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper12.html  In hindsight these do seem to be manipulating settings in Windows rather than in the SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable TRIM on the Mac, using either Trim Enabler ($10), or its newer sibling, Disk Sensei ($20), both from [Cindori](https://www.cindori.org/software/)

Late news: Apparently, Apple have allowed you to enable TRIM on any SSD since OS X 10.11.4
Using the Terminal command `sudo trim force enable` & acknowledging the big scary warning. The system will then reboot with TRIM enabled.
Thanks to Peter M & his link to Ars Technica : [Latest OS X update allows you to enable TRIM for third-party SSDs](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/06/latest-os-x-update-allows-you-to-enable-trim-for-third-party-ssds/) - though read the caveats in the comments section.

As for the rest, the only way I've ever been able to get firmware updates onto a Samsung was by reformatting it as NTFS & putting it in a PC, the Samsung app & instructions were of no use at all when I tried them on a Mac :(
Whether that is because I was trying to do it on an 08 Mac Pro which won't boot from their ISO, I might never know. How you would do it from a machine without an optical drive is also subject to experiment.

I have no experience with the Intel SSDs, so can't comment.

Comment: Theoretically you now don't need 3rd party tools to turn TRIM on. http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/06/latest-os-x-update-allows-you-to-enable-trim-for-third-party-ssds/

Comment: Ah, interesting news, thanks. I ought to add that to the answer.

Comment: But take a close look at the comments.  There seems to be an issue with TRIM deleting data on various manufacturers drives.  The caveat is that I have no experience in this subject and can only refer you to what is written there.

Comment: Oh, that sounds fun... though I've had TRIM enabled on my 840 since I got it - I guess time will tell. I do know that before I updated the firmware & reperformed it on the PC, it was already slowing down badly. It's been fine ever since.

Comment: Yeah .. total fun.  And here I am shopping around for my first SSD and I see thing like that!

Comment: We've got 4 here, 2 in Mac Pros, 2 in PCs, none have actually ever been any problem, other than having to clone, format NTFS, update... then back again every time there's a firmware update. There hasn't actually been an update in a long time for the 840, so all has been well since.

Comment: Reading to the end of those comments suggests that it might be a Linux rather than SSD issue.